# How make Current user as admin by using update query in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I need to do current user as admin. So I am trying to update my users table. In my user table there is a field called admin which has boolean datatype.

```
if current_user.admin != true
  current_user.update_attributes(:admin => 'true')
end
```

But this is not reflecting in my table. So what should I do here?

Comment: Can you show your `current_user` method please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
if current_user.admin != true
  current_user.admin = true #if admin is boolean
  current_user.save
end
```

This should work.

Comment: unecessary code - AR won't update attribute if value didn't changed.

Comment: I am not using the update_attributes. I am changing the value manually and saving it. So the change will be written. I am not using update_attribute.

Comment: so you are doing update_attributes by yourself. rails not doing something else. btw, even if you write the attribute - it will NOT be safed, unless the value changed...  so again, unecessary code... ^^

Comment: Updates a single attribute and saves the record without going through the normal validation procedure. This is especially useful for boolean flags on existing records. The regular update_attribute method in Base is replaced with this when the validations module is mixed in, which it is by default.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attribute

using rails-ways is always the way

Comment: Yeah. I agree that this is not the proper rails way.

Answer (score 0):

make it more "generic"

```
class User
  def grant_admin!
    update_attribute(:admin, true)
    # you dont need to check if he is alread an admin since rails won't 
    # write to DB unless any value changed
  end
end

# in controller
#...
current_user.grant_admin!
```

Do yourself a favor and have a look at https://github.com/ryanb/cancan and its railscasts